# How do I get solid text on a translucent background on a ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

### **`What I am trying to do`**:

- I am able to get rounded corners for images with `Picasso` using the image transformation class.
- But how do I get solid text on a `translucent` background on an `ImageView` as
  seen in the image below?
- I want to know how this is achieved both programatically and with XML.

[image]

### **`My XML`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/menu_type_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/cBlue"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can do it with 9patch instead of doing progmatically which is efficient.

Comment: you can add transparency to text color, and `TextView` background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it programmatically:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImage);
myImage.setAlpha(125); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
```

This is how you do it in XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wowimage"
    android:alpha=".55"/>
```